# Django Model Function Performance

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure how to title this question, please propose something better if you can!

I have two models.  The first model stored info for a tree (Tree).  The second is a model to store information when a tree is replanted (TreeResettlement).  A function in Tree called 'planted_date_real()' calculates the last time the tree was planted by looking at the latest record in TreeResettlement.

```
trees = Tree.objects.all()
for tree in trees:
   date = tree.planted_date_real()
```

I have performance issues with this.  Let's say 10000 trees are in the database.  If I call those 10000 trees, and want to know the last planted date, Django calls the TreeResettlement table 10000 times.

I'm aware of the 'select_related routine', however that only works if a Foreign Key is used in the table being worked on.

Any help will be appreciated!

** Note that I understand the planted_date_real() function has problems, it is used for illustrative purposes.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to use functions in models which can 'batch load' data and not do gazillion calls to the database when doing a function call (which filters a different table) on all objects in objects.filter() results

**Tree model**

```
class Tree(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    planted_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now,blank=True)

    def planted_date_real(self):
        #Calling data from TreeResettlement table is causing performance issues.  
        #Is there some way of loading this table to memory when the function is called again?
        resettlements = TreeResettlement.objects.filter(tree=self)

        if len(resettlements) > 0:
            return(resettlements[len(resettlements)-1].date)
        else:
            return(self.planted_date)
```

**TreeResettlement model**

```
class TreeResettlement(models.Model): 
    tree = models.ForeignKey(Tree,on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now,blank=True) 
    keep_main_stem = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: So you want the maximum resettlement date per tree?

Comment: Something like that yes - the max between what is in TreeResettlement table and planted_date field in Tree model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A function in Tree called `planted_date_real()` calculates the last time the tree was planted.

Well you here make assumptions about the database system that typically *not* hold. For example if you retrieve records, the order can be *any* order, not per se chronologically.

You can use an aggregate to obtain the maximum like:

```
from django.db.models import Max

class Tree(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    planted_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now,blank=True)

    def planted_date_real(self):
        last = self.treeresettlement_set.aggregate(last=Max('planted_date'))['last']
        return last or self.planted_date
```

If you however want to *annotate* all trees in bulk, this is still not very efficient, since this results in an *extra query* per tree. We can then annotate it like:

```
trees = Tree.objects.annotate(
    last_planted=Coalesce(Max('treeresettlement__planted_date'), 'planted_date')
)
```

So then every tree (of *this* queryset) will have an attribute `last_planted`, and these are all resolved in the *same* query.

Comment: Annotate looks promising.  I was hoping to have some way of keeping all the logic in a function in the model.  The function you are seeing is one of many, i just used the simplest one for illustration purposes

Comment: @ceds: well it is *still* in the model. In case you will only need to calcuate this for a limited number of trees, then it will work fine. But in case you need this in bulk, it is better to annotate.

Comment: So there is no way of doing a 'bulk' function (planted_date_real(self)) in the model?  That will need to happen outside?  I thought Django had some fancy way of loading the table into memory and not having to do 10000 db calls

Comment: @ceds: well you can for example override the object manager to encapsulate these calls, which might be the best way to hide all this annotation. But as far as I know, no; there is no elegant way to specify annotations.

Comment: thanks, I'll give some more time, maybe someone else has a fancy trick up their sleeves.  If nothing I'll go with your answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use last() function at your queryset while ordering to get the last record and return his date

```
def planted_date_real(self):  
    resettlement = TreeResettlement.objects.filter(tree=self).order_by("date").first()
    return resettlement.date
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/

**EDIT** :
If you want the last Tree just get it from TreeResettlement objects...

```
last_tree = TreeResettlement.objects.all().order_by("date").first().tree
```